# Random number generator generates same number until recompilation

Tags: java, random

Basically, I'm making a "scary" maze game and want the game over picture to change to a different picture every time you fail without having to recompile. Currently, the 'game over' picture stays the same every time you lose until you recompile.

```
public class MazeGame extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener 
{
private Random generator = new Random();

BufferedImage intro;
BufferedImage level1;
BufferedImage level2;
BufferedImage level3;
BufferedImage pic1;
BufferedImage pic2;
BufferedImage pic3;
BufferedImage pic4;
BufferedImage pic5;
BufferedImage gameOver;
BufferedImage currentLevel;
AudioClip spooky = JApplet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("gr/spooky.aiff"));

public MazeGame() throws IOException 
{
    intro = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/start.png"));
    level1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/level1.png"));
    level2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/level2.png"));
    level3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/level3.png"));
    pic1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/pic1.jpg"));
    pic2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/pic2.jpg"));
    pic3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/pic3.jpg"));
    pic4 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/pic4.jpg"));
    pic5 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("gr/pic5.jpg"));

    int number = 1 + generator.nextInt( 5 );
    gameOver = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource( "gr/pic" + number + ".jpg" ));

    currentLevel = intro;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Totally Not Scary Maze Game");
    MazeGame game = new MazeGame();
    window.add(game);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    game.addMouseMotionListener(game);
    game.addMouseListener(game);
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(800, 800);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

    g.drawImage(currentLevel, 0, 0, null);
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    int color = currentLevel.getRGB(x, y);

    System.out.println(color);

    int level1WallColor = -13939918;
    int level2WallColor = -10340732;
    int level3WallColor = -4640206;
    int goalColor = -14532251;

    if(color == goalColor) 
    {
        if(currentLevel == intro) 
        {
            currentLevel = level1;
        } 

        else if(currentLevel == level1) 
        {
            currentLevel = level2;
        }

        else if(currentLevel == level2) 
        {
            currentLevel = level3;
        }

        else if(currentLevel == level3)
        {
            showGameOver();
        }
    }

    if(color == level1WallColor) 
    {
        showGameOver();
    }

    if(color == level2WallColor) 
    {
        currentLevel = intro;
    }

    if(color == level3WallColor) 
    {
        showGameOver();
    }

    repaint();
}

private void showGameOver() 
{
    currentLevel = gameOver;
    spooky.play();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if(currentLevel == gameOver) 
    {
        currentLevel = intro;
    }

    repaint();
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

}
```

Comment: I can't see where you call new mazegame() the 2nd time? In the constructor, this is where background image is selected?

Comment: @minh-kieu got it first and so I won't answer. You need to call the line 'gameOver = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource( "gr/pic" + number + ".jpg" ));' after every lose.

Comment: @Ray-Falk so where exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are always setting cuurentLevel as Intro at the the end Mazegame(). Comment this line and try.

```
 currentLevel = intro;
```

Also I read your code superficially.. Not sure I see where exactly the switching of the picture will happen. You will call your changePic(i.e your mazegame()) right after where the fail is evaluated. so Everytime the evaluation happens failed user will get a changed pic.

Comment: Doing this just paints the game gray. That line of code sets which level the game starts at.

Comment: Since this code has some logic built in, obviously something is wrong. IC an sussgest, you can write a small single method in a new program that will do only the following. 1. Load image set ur level flag 1 , 2. set ur level flag to 2 and change image there. This way you can make sure that there is nothing else going with paint / repaint stuff. And then you can figure out what is going on with this logic. Other wise i feel u will feel blind as to what is going on. Also Debug if you can and write the logic step by step, you WILL hit the line which is incorrect.